# Intersect Automapper collection processing

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following structure:

```
public class Destination
{
   public Destination()
   {
      _StringCollection = new List<String>();
   }
   private ICollection<String> _StringCollection;
   public IEnumerable<String> StringCollection
   {
     get
     {
       return _StringCollection.AsEnumerable<String>();
     }
   }

   public void AddString(string str)
   {
      _StringCollection.Add(str);
   }
 }

 public class Source
 {
    public List<String> StringCollection { get; set; }
 }
```

I would like to map that for each member of source call AddString(member) on Destination.

I thought that maybe I could do something with a custom resolver but can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AfterMap` to run `AddString` for each string in source:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .AfterMap((src,dest) => {
            foreach (var s in src.StringCollection)
                dest.AddString(s);
        }));
```